# Android Reinstall the app instead of update?

Tags: android

Okay so I made a update to one of my app, but if the users automatically updates the app will encounter some errors, so I was wondering if there's a way to tell In Google Developer Console to reinstall the app instead of updating it?

Or in manifest?

And if there is a way to do this, the users phones will still automatically "update" the app?

If not, Can I programatically "Clear Cache" of my app? without adding a permission.

If I understand right if I add a new permission the users phones will **not** update automatically?

Comment: In case if you have made a bo bo in your new App. Then I would do the following. 
a) Create a new App and launch it on Google Play
b) Send another update for my existing App to my users. That update would be to redirect it to my new Google App on Play.  
c) I'm trying to migrate all my users to the New App. Hence then deleting the older App.

Comment: @MDMalik thanks for the reply, but Im not willing to loose all the app reviews just yet

Comment: Yes, you can "clear the cache" a number of ways but need to know more about the crash first. What do the crash logs say?

Comment: @Tigger the crash is because in the older app I save all the settings in a string and get them splitting the string, but as I modified the app some values are not correct or just don't exist, so when the new app tries to read the settings string crashes. If I can clear the app cache wouldn't be so bad for the users, cuz settings are simple and can get them back in a few clicks

Comment: you should modify your app in a way, that it could also read old settings without crash and release as soon as possible a new version. it should be possible to find the wrong implementation. From your description, it should be simply be done by creating default values for the new ones. Why you haven´t  used sharedPreferences to store the settings instead of saving all into a string?